# Countdown timer to control gameplay sessions

Tags: windows, time-management

I need a simple countdown timer to help to control my gameplay sessions on PC, just to help me to organize my time.

As all we know, when you run a game in a PC (to be more specific it is a gaming prepared laptop, so a embedded solution is what I need), it generally takes all the screen, covering the OS clock. Since I want to keep the game in full screen mode and want to track my spend time on it, these are the features I'm searching for this software:

**Required**

- Works on Windows
- Simple set time and countdown start
- Ability to put on top of the game, even it was in full screen mode
- Opacity level selection to give full translucent level, or enough to not interfere in the gameplay session
- Play a sound when the time is near to the end.
- Size selection
- Free screen positioning

**Desired**

- Linux compatibility
- Free to use

Comment: The placement on top of the game might not be possible without stealing focus. I use another monitor or a phone app

Comment: @Timmy that's why the requirements of opacity, size and positioning are in the question. If I have my smartphone around a lot of other notifications will compromise my focus.

Comment: Why not a plain and old clock on the table/wall right next to the computer? Put an alarm clock and you have a nice way of interrumpting yourself. Nothing techie or fancy, just 50 years old technology :P

Comment: @Alejandro to be more specific it is a gaming prepared laptop, so a embedded solution is what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first I can think of is [Overwolf](http://www.overwolf.com/). Actually, the application itself doesn't match with your desired functions and options but you can download an additional app to get a ingame clock. Overwolf works with a wide range of applications, however, it doesn't support every single one. You can adjust the opacity as you require it. It worked fine for me as I tested it.

However, you can always view your spent time on a game by using [xFire](http://xfire.com/) or [GamePlay Time Tracker](http://www.gameplay-time-tracker.info/). These solution don't offer an ingame overhaul.

A more creative solution would be [OnTopReplica](http://www.klopfenstein.net/lorenz.aspx/ontopreplica). It's an application that forces other applications to be always on top. So basically you can set up an external alarm clock program which will be forced to stay on top. The window can be freely placed anywhere while you're playing. A possible external timer program is [Orzeszek Timer](http://www.orzeszek.org/dev/timer/). You can adjust the opacity in OnTopReplica, too.

Comment: Overwolf do the trick, but it is very intrusive IMO.  OnTopReplica is not capable to put windows on top of games. If this was possible, it would be the best solution with Orzeszek Timer. Anyway the answer was very valuable just because it makes me know these wonderfull, yet simple, applications (except here for Overwolf).